# What is the MD5 file in R packages used for? How is it generated?

Tags: r, md5, r-package

I have noticed a file called 'MD5' is present in the directories of many R packages that I have downloaded. However I can not find a mention of this in the 'Writing R Extensions' manual. It lists the MD5 hash and filename for different files in the package.
What is this file used for? Should it be something I include in my packages? How can it be generated?

Comment: Have you checked out `?md5sum`?

Comment: Yes. It generates MD5 hashes for a list of files you give it, but it doesn't tell you what this file is for or format the output in the same way.

Answer (score 9):

The MD5 hash file found in the R packages is used to uniquely identify the package `src` on a repository (e.g. CRAN).

Specifically, when the package is listed in a repo, the meta data of the package is added to a file called `PACKAGES`. When a user requests a package via `install.packages()`, a download is triggered that checks for the MD5 hash. This is stated in the `?md5sum` function

> MD5 sums are used as a check that R packages have been unpacked correctly and not subsequently modified.

The inside of a `PACKAGES` file would look like:

```
Package: datapkg
Version: 2.0.0
Depends: R (>= 3.2)
License: file LICENSE
MD5sum: 22797605db853f5f4c2c5612da366b53
NeedsCompilation: no
```

For more information on how repos work with `install.packages()`, please see the post that I wrote:

http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/r-data-packages-in-external-data-repositories-using-the-additional_repositories-field/

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: The `MD5sum:` line in `DESCRIPTION` is not the same thing as the package MD5 file. The file has a different purpose. See my answer below. :-)

Answer (score 5):

The file is used as input to `tools::checkMD5sums()` and checks the integrity of the installed package. The format can be reverse engineered from the code: a text file that has a line for each included file, containing the MD5 hash, a `*` separator, and the file path relative to the specified root directory. You can create these by hand from the output of `tools::md5sum()` - or you can use a function that I have provided in [**this Gist**](https://gist.github.com/hyginn/6a59e75e66198be6dbc3aa1602b2df04), where I also discuss this in more detail.

Comment: Very nice Gist! However, note that an internal function for generating the MD5 file does exist (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75277189/570918)).

Comment: Thank you, and yes - you are right. Keep in mind that non-exported functions may change at any time, are typically not easily discoverable, and – since there are no comments about their intent – their use requires assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

### Generating MD5 file

There is a non-exported function `tools:::.installMD5sums(pkgDir, outDir = pkgDir)` that can generate the `MD5` file. I've commented the essential steps here:

```r
## compute check sum for every file in package
x <- md5sum(dir(".", recursive = TRUE))

## exclude any existing "MD5" file
x <- x[names(x) != "MD5"]

## write each result out to the "MD5" file
cat(paste(x, names(x), sep = " *"), sep = "\n", 
    file = file.path(outDir, "MD5"))
```

One can use it like:

```
tools:::.installMD5sums("/path/to/pkg/")
```

Answer (score -1):

I arrived here from googling for how to get an md5 hash of a file. This method is simple and effective:

```
library(openssl)
as.character(md5(file("path/to/yourfile.txt", open = "rb")))
# [1] "30621b64b2232a67900738ab471f2067"
```